# print all content after =

Tags: awk, sed

I am try to parse one text file where I need to get all the content after "inventory = ". The question might look very easy for you but I am not good in parsing text file hence asking this question.

Input File

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat file
inventory = #########################################


        Ansible Inventory File


#########################################
[targets]
localhost      ansible_connection=local
192.168.44.134
192.168.44.200

[jewels]
192.168.44.200  ansible_connection=local        abc=test
192.168.44.134

[apple]
localhost       ansible_connection=local
0               ansible_connection=local

[fruits:children]
jewels
apple
```

Output should be

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat file

 #########################################


         Ansible Inventory File


 ######################################### 
 [targets] 
 localhost      ansible_connection=local
 192.168.44.134
 192.168.44.200

 [jewels]
 192.168.44.200  ansible_connection=local        abc=test
 192.168.44.134

 [apple] localhost       ansible_connection=local 0              
 ansible_connection=local

 [fruits:children] jewels apple
```

Comment: It looks like you are printing all the file by your sample? Is there any specific place in file here you need to stop printing it?  Then be mention it clearly.

Comment: Also if string inventory is not found e should not print anything from file? kinly confirm this too once.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, if you take a look in output section "inventory = " is missing

Comment: So you want a tool to remove the `0<spaces>` from the line that starts with that, add `><blank>` to the start of every line and remove the newline between `jewels` and `apple` in the last 2 lines of the file, right? If not - fix your example to demonstrate what it is you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. I am assuming that you are only looking for string `invetory=` in your Input_file and if that is not found then you DO NOT want to print anything in Input_file.

```
awk '/^inventory =/{sub(/.*inventory = +/,"");found=1} found'  Input_file
```

Comment: @user3847894, then you could try this if your question is having good enough details in it.

Comment: It is completely deleting the first line

Comment: @user3847894, could you please try `awk '/^inventory =/{sub(/.*inventory = +/,"");found=1} found'  Input_file` this one once?

Comment: @user3847894, please check my edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,arr," = "); print arr[2]; while (getline == 1) print $0}' file
```

getline will start reading from second line until the end of the line

or

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1; i<=42; i++) printf "#"; while (getline == 1) print $0}' file
```

Comment: IMHO, `getline` could do weird things if not properly used in code so please be aware.

Comment: ...and it's completely inappropriate for this task. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. Also that split() approach will fail when there's multiple `=`s on the line and hard-coding how many lines your input needs to have is obviously a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for that link. It contains a wealth of info about getline.

Answer (score 1):

From your description `I need to get all the content after "inventory = "` it sounds like this is what you want as it will do exactly that:

```
awk 'sub(/.*inventory = /,""){f=1} f' file
```

but idk since your posted sample input/output don't seem to reflect just that.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working fine. Sorry I edited the output

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl as it is the right choice for these situations.

```
perl -0777 -ne ' /inventory =(.*)/s and print $1 '
```

with your inputs.

```
$ cat inventory.txt
inventory = #########################################


        Ansible Inventory File


#########################################
[targets]
localhost      ansible_connection=local
192.168.44.134
192.168.44.200

[jewels]
192.168.44.200  ansible_connection=local        abc=test
192.168.44.134

[apple]
localhost       ansible_connection=local
0               ansible_connection=local

[fruits:children]
jewels
apple
$  perl -0777 -ne ' /inventory =(.*)/s and print $1 ' inventory.txt
 #########################################


        Ansible Inventory File


#########################################
[targets]
localhost      ansible_connection=local
192.168.44.134
192.168.44.200

[jewels]
192.168.44.200  ansible_connection=local        abc=test
192.168.44.134

[apple]
localhost       ansible_connection=local
0               ansible_connection=local

[fruits:children]
jewels
apple
$
```